# Unable to access route params (functional component)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to pass the username from signup1 to signup 2:

```
handleSignUp = () => {
      console.log(this.state.username) <------------- This logs correctly 

      try {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup2', {
          username: this.state.username, <------------- Passing here
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

Here is the code from Signup2:

```
const Signup2 = (props, route, navigation) => {

  const { username } = route.params; <----------- Trying to access it here
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.username')
```

I have also tried this:

```
const { username } = props.route.params
```

And neither work.

How can I access the route params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to destructure your route and navigation properties if you'd like to access them as intended.

You can go for:

```
const Signup2 = ({route, navigation}) => {
   const { username } = route.params
}
```

Or maybe:

```
const Signup2 = (props) => {
   const { username } = props.route.params
}
```